# Ubuntu 17.10 | Peripheral issues

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, mouse, peripherals

I've been a huge fan of ubuntu for a long time now and I'm finally dedicating a whole HDD to it instead of using a virtual machine. I just installed it and I've ran in to some errors that I'm not finding any answers to online. 

**Issue:**

- Peripherals (Mouse & Keyboard); have terribly slow response time. If I move my mouse(if it even reads it), it'll react 15-20 seconds later. Same with keystrokes. (other than in the terminal. My keyboard seems to behave fine there which is strange to me).

**Note: If there are any logs I can post to make diagnostics easier for you just let me know and I'll gladly supply them.*

**Specs:**

- AMD FX-8320
- GTX 1060 6GB
- 16GB DDR3
- 750 PWS
- 500GB HDD

Answer (score 0):

Did these issues occur when using the live "cd"? (you probably used it on a USB stick).

If you haven't installed/activated a driver for your Nvidia card yet, I'd start there.

If you're using a wireless mouse, I would try plugging in the receiver into a different port to see if that helps.